# I did something to my bashrc or something in UNIX, not listed in sudoers file anymore and can not get access to directories

Tags: sudo, chmod, stat

I am using REDHAT/CENTOS 6.5.

I used to have access to directories, but now when I try to go into them after I rebooted by UNIX, it tells me that permission is denied.

Using stat command on these directories it seems my user (which is not root) does not have access to these directories anymore even though I created them with this user.  I might have corrupted, erased or done something to my `.bashrc` or some other file - I am a novice in UNIX.

Then, I try `sudo chmod go+rx` on the directory, its asks for the user name password and I enter it and it says "user" (user being my user name locally) is not in the sudoers file and this incident will be reported.

I think I erased some files in my root directory.

What did I do or erase to cause this to happen and how can I fix it?

Also when I change to root user now, the command line just says -bash-4.1 and nothing else.  I must have erased something in the root directory or something.  I am new to UNIX so I am not sure.

Can this be fixed?

Update: Now it seems I cannot write anything in the directories also.

Comment: Do you remember running a `chmod` command with the `-R` flag on anydirectories, possibly `/` or `/usr`?

Answer (score 0):

First, become root using `su -`

Fix the root's homedir:

```
mkdir /root
cp -a /etc/skel/.* /root/
```

Make sure your own username is in `wheel` group:

```
usermod -a -G wheel yourusername
```

Make sure wheel group can sudo. Open `/etc/sudoers` using `visudo` and make sure this line exists and is not commented (no `#` in the beginning of the line):

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Reboot.

Comment: You shouldn't edit `/etc/sudoers` with anything other than the `visudo` command -- if you mess up its contents, you can easily make a bad situation even worse.

Comment: Thanks @GordonDavisson . Updated the answer

Comment: Whats in cp -a /etc/skel/.* ??

Comment: @sheeple That contains the dotfiles like `.bashrc`, `.profile`. You can `cd /etc/skel` and `ls -a` to see for yourself.